# Setting conversion goal for multilingual URLs (GA)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website on which the URLs are translated depending on the language chosen by the user.

Now, I need to set up conversion goals in GA, however I'm not sure how to do it in my case. Let's say I want to track registrations via **About us** page. The goal(s) would look like this:

**(EN)**

1. /
2. /about-us
3. /registration
4. /dashboard

**(DE)**

1. /
2. /über-uns
3. /registrierung
4. /dashboard

As you see, steps 2 and 3 differ in terms of language used. BUT, this still is **the same goal**.

How do I handle this in GA? I would prefer to have single statistic for this, instead of separating both language versions.

I know that I could set up **custom pageviews** but this seems like an overkill. Is there a simpler way to achieve what I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need a funnel you can send an event with a language agnostic identifier along with the pageview and make an event goal. This is only marginally simpler that custom pagenames in your tracking calls, but at least you get to keep the original urls.

As an alternative to goals altogether you could set up a hit-scoped custom metric that is incremented on each of your destination urls. This works well if you only need the raw numbers (but you cannot use this in Google Adwords the way you export goals to Adwords, so it's less useful if you do paid advertising).

Comment: I see. Good thing is most of my cases are not linear, so I can make most of the steps optional or skip them, and setup a pageview for the goal-page. Anyway, thanks for the insight, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RegEx (regular expressions) then, If " registration / registrierung " is your goal the use following as:

registration|registrierung

- For setting up make sure you select - Regular Expression at
  Destination type in Goal details.
- The PIPE b/w would mean - OR - in Regex
- You can apply this to goal funnels as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to include step 1? I would leave exclude it from the goal funnel

These regxes below would work in a funnel but the they assume that there could be other params added. If you want exact match e.g. change .* to $ But then you could miss urls with tracking params e.g. in each step.

1. Second step: ^\/(about-us|über-uns).*
2. Third step: ^\/(registration|registrierung).*
3. Goal page: ^\/dashboard.*